# Widget extension framework not found error and Multiple commands produce errors Xcode 14.XX fix

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In Xcode 14.XX I have added a `Widget extension` to an old project the to support the new Dynamic Island feature in iOS 16.XX.

In the project there is already a Widget extension and Pods including Firebase (Core, Crashlytics etc').

When I add the extension and try to compile I get These errors :

```
Multiple commands produce /Users.......
```

After fixing the above error I get `id Framework not found FirebaseCore` (in my case).

How do I fix these errors ?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who struggles with this issue here is the solution I came up with.

Tested on **Xcode 14.2 iOS 16.2** on a old Objective C project which includes Swift and Flutter.

First register a Bundle id in the Apple Developer portal for your new Widget.
Then in Xcode **New -> Target -> Widget Extension** in the create window make sure it has the same name as the Bundle id you created in the provisioning profile at your Apple Developer portal click ok.

Then go to your **Widget extension Target under Signing & Capabilities** and if your certificate management is not set to automatic import or download the profile.

Then if you try to compile you are likely (in my case anyway) get this compile error :

```
Multiple commands produce /Users.......
```

To solve this error go the **Widget extension Target -> Build Settings** and type in the search **module name** under there if the name is identical to your main target name change it to whatever name you like as long as its different and this should resolve this error.

After you try to build again in my case I got a compiler error that says :

```
id Framework not found FirebaseCore
```

To fix error again **under build settings on the Widget Target** go to -> B**uild Settings -> other linker flags** and remove all the values from it (if there are any).

This should solve this compiler error and the project should build and run.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi @rony_y I tried to add WidgetKit extension and my app doesn't run. I get an error saying "This app contains an app extension that specifies an extension point identifier that is not supported on this version of iOS for the value of the NSExtensionPointIdentifier key in its Info.plist." Can you help me with this?